# Qual a diferença entre carriage return e line feed?

Tags: string, independente-de-linguagem, quebras-de-linha

Existem duas formas diferentes de quebrar uma linha CR (*carriage return*) e LF (*line feed*).

Qual a diferença entre essas duas? Quando deve-se usar uma ou outra? Depende do sistema? Da linguagem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Como o nome diz o CR faz voltar para o início da linha e o LF é para ir para a próxima linha. A grosso modo é o fim da linha. Isso vem do fato que as impressoras trabalhavam assim.

Em tese eles deveriam funcionar independentes e para ir para o começo da próxima linha deveria usar ambos. Mas alguns sistemas convencionaram interpretar apenas um deles como a intenção de fazer as duas ações, até para economia de espaço.

Como em muita coisa na computação, depende de quem está interpretando. É comum escolhermos o CR (Mac Os) ou o LF (Linux) ou o CR+LF (Windows) dependendo do sistema operacional porque muitas ferramentas dele foram feitas para interpretar só de um desses jeitos. Mas cada ferramenta pode dar a semântica que quiser para isto.

Isto não quer dizer que um sistema operacional trabalha com um terminador, apenas as ferramentas disponíveis nele preferem ou só aceitam um terminador específico. As melhores ferramentas tentam se adaptar.

No fundo eles são os caracteres 13 e 10 da tabela ASCII, então em vários cenários isto não quer dizer nada com tratamento de linhas de texto. Onde há uma semântica nesse sentido, tem que ver a documentação.

Você pode criar um formato que eles são interpretados como você queira. Pode nem usá-los para terminar uma linha. Só fugirá do padrão.

Depende de tudo isso e é comum quando vai trocar dados de texto entre sistemas operacionais ou mesmo entre ferramentas específicas.

A maioria das linguagens possuem uma forma de abstrair o indicador de final de linha e ela - via compilador ou *runtime* - se encarrega de usar os caracteres corretos em cada sistema operacional.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md)

Answer (score 1):

Para o propósito que foram definidos, nos primordios da informática, representam comandos de impressão literalmente.
Como tudo era visto como impressão(*inclusive a saída para o monitor*) se fazia necessário passar comandos específicos (*utilizados até hoje em muitos casos*) de formatação que não seriam impressos (visíveis para o usuário) mas interpretados pelos hardwares (impressora, monitor, etc.).

### Exemplo prático:

- 1. Imagine uma máquina de escrever (das antigas), o *LF* (*line feed*) seria o ato de avançar uma linha, e o *CR* (*carriage return*) seria quando você puxaria o carro para a primeira coluna da página.
- 2. Em uma impressora, funcionda da mesma forma: Ao receber a string de impressão ela inicia o trabalho, ao perceber o *LF* durante a impressão, ela simplemente avança a linha da página mantendo a cabeça de impressão no mesmo lugar, ao perceber o *CR* ela volta a cabeça de impressão para a primeira coluna da página.
- 3. Práticamente a mesma coisa acontece em um ambiente de terminal (console), *LF* pula(avança) uma linha e *CR* volta o cursor para o ínicio da linha.

### No final a diferença é clara

- LF (*line feed*): Quebra linha, avança linha ou pula linda (como queira).
- CR (*carriage return*): Retorna o cursor para primeira coluna.