# Qual é a diferença entre "\n" e "\r\n" (caracteres especiais para quebra de linha)?

Tags: sistema-operacional, quebras-de-linha

Para quebra de linhas, costumo utilizar `\n`. Porém percebo que em alguns caso, como por exemplo no editor Sublime Text, alguns textos que preciso capturar a quebra-de-linha só são capturados quando eu uso a regex `\r\n`.

Já li algumas coisas na internet sobre `\r\n` e a única coisa que entendi é que este tem alguma coisa relacionada ao *Sistema Operacional Windows*.

Em alguns casos, tive problema com a utilização do `\n` em um sistema de downloads para arquivos `txt`. Esse sistema está escrito em PHP. Precisei substituir as quebras de linha `\n` para `\r\n` para o texto ser interpretado da maneira correta. Mas isso me deixou em dúvidas se o problema era relacionado ao sistema operacional ou a linguagem de programação PHP.

Sendo assim:

- Qual é a diferença entre `\n` e `\r\n`?
- Quando eu deveria usar um ou outro?
- Isso está relacionado ao sistema operacional que eu uso, ou a linguagem de programação (como no exemplo do PHP)?

Comment: `\r` = return e `\n` = newline, se esta desenvolvendo php é utilize `nl2br` e segue http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php ... depende o que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado @KingRider. Na verdade o problema nem é o PHP, eu apenas fiz uma sitação. Note que não adicionei a tag [tag:php]. Isso porque eu quero entender realmente o signficado, quando devo usar, entre outras coisas.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93444/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-carriage-return-e-line-feed

Answer (score 32, accepted):

O `\n` significa "*new line*" ou "*line-feed*", ou seja, "nova linha". O `\r` significa "*carriage return*", ou seja "retorno de carro". Quando a tabela ASCII foi padronizada, o `\n` recebeu o código 10 e `\r` recebeu o código 13.

A ideia originalmente, quando as tabelas de codificação de caracteres como sequências de bits foram concebidas, é que o `\n` fosse interpretado como o comando para fazer o cursor se mover para baixo, e o `\r` o comando para ele se mover de volta até o começo da linha. Essa distinção era importante para as máquinas de escrever digitais que precederam os computadores, para telégrafos digitais, para teletipos e para a programação das primeiras impressoras que surgiram. De fato, isso é surpreendentemente mais antigo do que se pensa, [já aparecendo no ano de 1901](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code) junto com algumas das primeiras dessas tabelas de codificação de caracteres.

Assim sendo, em um texto para que uma quebra-de-linha fosse inserida, fazia-se necessário utilizar-se `\r\n`. Primeiro o cursor deveria se mover até o começo da linha e depois para baixo. E foi esse o padrão de quebra-de-linha adotado muito mais tarde pela Microsoft.

Já o Multics (e posteriormente o Unix) seguiram um caminho diferente, e decidiram implementar o `\n` como quebra-de-linha, o que já incluía um retorno de carro. Afinal de contas, não tem lá muito sentido ter uma coisa sem ter a outra junto, e ao utilizá-los como sendo uma coisa só, garante-se que nunca serão separados. Isso também tem a vantagem de economizar espaço ao usar um só byte para codificar a quebra-de-linha ao invés de dois, e naqueles anos aonde a memória era pequena e o processamento de baixo poder, cada byte economizado contava bastante.

Outras empresas, como a Apple e a Commodore, também seguiram um caminho semelhante ao do Unix, mas ao invés de adotarem o `\n` para quebras-de-linha, adotaram o `\r`.

Outras empresas menores adotaram outros códigos para a quebra-de-linha. Por exemplo, o QNX adotou o caractere 30 da tabela ASCII. A Atari adotou o 155. A Acorn e o RISC OS adotaram o `\n\r` ao invés de `\r\n`. A Sinclair adotou o 118.

Fontes:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return

Comment: Muito muito bom +1.

Answer (score 8):

De acordo com o mesmo [tópico em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them):

\r = CR (Carriage Return) // Usado como quebra de linha no Mac OS anterior à versão X

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Usado como quebra de linha Unix/Mac OS superior à versão X

\r\n = CR + LF // Usado como quebra de linha no Windows

### Quando devo usar cada um?

#### Geração de arquivos

Numa gravação de arquivo de log, por exemplo, que será executado/processado por uma outra aplicação, é importante que siga-se o padrão do ambiente, já que a aplicação de destino também o fará. Fazer isso é recomendado apenas se você está escrevendo um código para um ambiente específico.
O PHP possui uma constante reservada [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) (recomendo fortemente), que resolverá a quebra de linha pra você de acordo com o ambiente, assim você fará seu código multi-plataforma, com relação à quebra de linhas.

#### HTML

Enviando o conteúdo (texto) de um arquivo para ser renderizado pelo browser, é interessante usar a função `nl2br` que converterá todas as quebras de linha em `<br />`.

Comment: Qual é a diferença? Quando eu deveria usar? A parte do sistema operacional está dando para subentender, embora a resposta não fale diretamente.

Comment: Isso vai depender do seu objetivo e do sistema operacional. Por exemplo, se você estiver imprimindo um html para o navegador, seria bom usar a função `nl2br` do PHP. No caso de gravar um arquivo de log,  que será processado por outro recurso por exemplo, considere o padrão do SO de destino, já que aplicações, bibliotecas, etc, farão o tratamento do seu arquivo no padrão do ambiente.

Comment: Acho que isso poderia estar na sua resposta então. Acho que ela vai ficar melhor. Assim, creio que os usuários removerão os negativos.

Comment: Complementei a resposta. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, jovem. isso é bom :D