# Como imprimir pulando linhas (cada variável em uma linha)?

Tags: python

Como imprimir pulando linhas (cada  variável em uma linha)?

```
nome ='Paulo'
profissao = 'estudante'
escola = 'estadual dourado'
idade = 18


print 'Nome: '+nome   + 'Trabalho: '+profissao +  'Escola: ' +escola+   'Idade: '+str(idade)+ ' anos'
```

Comment: Erro meu! Desculpem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim:

```
nome ='Paulo'
profissao = 'estudante'
escola = 'estadual dourado'
idade = 18


print 'Nome: '+nome   + '\nTrabalho: '+profissao +  '\nEscola: ' +escola+   '\nIdade: '+str(idade)+ ' anos'
```

Nota para python3.x seria:

```
print('Nome: '+nome   + '\nTrabalho: '+profissao +  '\nEscola: ' +escola+   '\nIdade: '+str(idade)+ ' anos')
```

Mas atenção, a maneira mais aconselhada para este contexto é o [format](https://pyformat.info/):

```
print 'Nome: {}\nTrabalho: {}\nEscola: {}\nIdade: {} anos'.format(nome, profissao, escola, idade)
```

Comment: +1 A pergunta está completa e com muitas opções, Miguel. Parabéns pelas explicações.

Comment: Obgado @WallaceMaxters :)

Comment: @Miguel, obrigado...

Comment: De nada @PauloSouza, eu apostaria no format. É sempre melhor e menos confuso

Answer (score 3):

Creio que você possa usar multiplos `print`. Na minha opinião, facilita a compreensão do seu código:

```
 #Define as variáveis de jeito mais organizado

 nome, idade = ("Wallace", 26)

 print "Nome: " + nome

 print "Idade: " + str(idade)
```

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/7FwadF)

Você também pode usar a formatação de print combinada com o `\n`:

```
 print "Nome : %s\nIdade :%s" % (nome, idade)
```

Em sistemas operacionais `Windows`, você teria que usar `\r\n` ao invés de `\n`. Veja o porquê aqui:

- [Qual é a diferença entre "\n" e "\r\n" (caracteres especiais para quebra de linha)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146048/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-n-e-r-n-caracteres-especiais-para-quebra-de-linh)

Answer (score -2):

```
print 'Nome: '+nome + '\n'  + 'Trabalho: '+profissao + '\n' + 'Escola: ' +escola+ '\n' + 'Idade: '+str(idade)+ ' anos'
```

Basta usar o caractere   `\n`   no locais da frase que você quiser pular a linha. Cada   `\n`  é uma linha pulada!