# Qual a funcionalidade de \n?

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo a programar em Python e algumas coisas básica ainda me confundem, por exemplo esta pergunta que fiz. Qual a utilidade do \n?

Comment: Não conheço Pyton, mas creio que seja para pular uma linha no script. Este comando é usado para pular linha em algumas linguagens.

Comment: Relacioandas: [Qual a diferença entre carriage return e line feed?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93444/91) e [Qual é a diferença entre “\n” e “\r\n” \(caracteres especiais para quebra de linha\)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146048/91)

Comment: Este tipo de sequência de escape não são características de uma linguagem de programação específica. Veja, por exemplo, https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequ%C3%AAncia_de_escape.

Answer (score 13):

Python utiliza o caractere `\n` para quebra de linhas.

Perceba que mesmo sendo composto por dois caracteres, ele representa apenas um na tabela ASCII: o caractere 10. Ele também é conhecido por ASCII LF, onde LF vem de *line feed*. A presença da barra invertida antecedendo o caractere `n` significa sequência de escape. Em outras palavras, estamos informando que este `n` não é a letra "êne", mas sim o comando de quebra de linha.

Como comentado na pergunta, algumas leituras interessantes:

- [Qual é a diferença entre "\n" e "\r\n" (caracteres especiais para quebra de linha)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146048/5878)
- [Qual a diferença entre carriage return e line feed?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93444/5878)

No Python, todas as sequências escapadas serão interpretadas quando presentes dentro de um texto (*string*). Isto é, se você pedir para o Python exibir a mensagem:

```
print("Ola\nMundo")
```

A sequência escapada estará em uma *string* e, portanto, será analisada, gerando a saída:

```
Ola
Mundo
```

Mas nem sempre é esta saída que desejamos obter, pois pode acontecer de sua *string* utilizar naturalmente a barra invertida. Por exemplo, o caminho de um diretório no Windows poderia ser:

```
C:\temp\novos\foto.png
```

Se você fizer no Python:

```
print("C:\temp\novos\foto.png")
```

A saída gerada seria:

```
C:  emp
ovosoto.png
```

Isso porquê a sequência escapada `\t` representa uma tabulação e, portanto, é inserido um espaçamento dentro da *string*; a sequência `\n` é uma quebra de linha e a sequência `\f` não é reconhecida, então é ignorada. Neste caso, você pode adicionar um prefixo `r` à sua *string* para indicar ao Python que você deseja o seu texto da maneira que está, sem analisá-lo:

```
print(r"C:\temp\novos\foto.png")
```

- [Quais são e qual a função de cada prefixo de string no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255271/5878)
- [Qual é a diferença entre 'string' e r'string' em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80545/5878)

Desta forma, a saída será exatamente o texto esperado:

```
C:\temp\novos\foto.png
```

Outra forma é escapar a sequência escapada (sim, você leu certo). Na verdade, o que é feito é escapar o caractere da barra invertida, indicando que aquela barra invertida não deve ser analisada como caractere de escape. Isto é:

```
print("C:\\temp\\novos\\foto.png")
```

Desta forma, o resultado produzido é idêntico ao utilizar o prefixo `r` no texto.

No Python ainda existe a sequência escapada `\N` **que não deve ser confundida** com `\n`. No primeiro o N é maiúsculo e no segundo é minúsculo. Pode parecer que não faz diferença, mas faz. Quando utilizado o prefixo `u` no texto desejado, indicando ao Python para interpretar o texto como Unicode, a sequência `\N` é utilizada para inserir caracteres através do seu nome - no Python 3, o prefixo `u` é desnecessário. Por exemplo, ao fazer:

```
print(u"\N{BLACK SPADE SUIT}")
```

A saída gerada é:

```
♠
```

Answer (score 5):

QUEBRAR LINHAS.

o código: `print "Fisrt line!\nSecond line!"` tem a seguinte saída:

[image: quebra de linha]

Answer (score 1):

\n usado para pular linhas

```
nome ='Paulo'
profissao = 'estudante'
escola = 'estadual dourado'
idade = 18

print 'Nome: '+nome   + 'Trabalho: '+profissao +  'Escola: ' +escola

print 'Nome: '+nome   + '\nTrabalho: '+profissao +  '\nEscola: ' +escola
```

- [resultado - ideone - python](https://ideone.com/9OVWZr)

> O funcionamento do caractere no Python tem o mesmo comportamento no JS, portanto, deixo aqui um exemplo em JS por questão de praticidade.

- Exemplo em javascript

```js
var nome ='Paulo'
var profissao = 'estudante'
var escola = 'estadual dourado'
var idade = 18;
 
 
var result = 'Nome: '+nome   + 'Trabalho: '+profissao +  'Escola: ' +escola;
 
var result2 =  'Nome: '+nome   + '\nTrabalho: '+profissao +  '\nEscola: ' +escola;
 
console.log(result);
 
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

é um tipo de break line que é usado para "quebrar" a linha de código
assim

```
print("ola mundo \r\n exemplo")
```

a saída será assim

```
ola mundo
exemplo
```

Comment: ok obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 0):

> Estou aprendendo a programar em Python e algumas coisas básica ainda me confundem, por exemplo esta pergunta que fiz. Qual a utilidade do \n?

Em qualquer arquivo de texto a linha só termina de fato com um `\n`. Ele não aparece pois é omitido, exatamente pelo fato de ter esta função.
Ele corresponde com o `10` em Decimal que é `0xA`.

Python é uma linguagem de alto-nível então muitos conceitos as vezes são deixados de lado. OBS: Não estou julgando ninguém, serei claro e objetivo.

O caractere contra-barra(`\`) é chamado de **Escape**, ou seja, você pode adicionar "coisas especiais a seu código."
Normalmente todo arquivo contendo textos tem esse escape `\n` no final de cada linha.

Ex:

```
print("Fiat              - \n lux") # Perceba que só mudou a linha após o \n
```

**TABELA ASCII**

**Ok, mas o que você quer dizer com isso?**

[image: 1KB de .jpg valem mais que 1024MB de .txt]

Agora vamos ao **hexadecimal character escape**. Ok eu sei, agora você entendeu tudo hehehe, mas calma.

Na imagem temos que DEC 10 = **char LF**(e algumas explicações assim como new line(nova linha)). Ok, e daí?

Agora vamos pegar os valores **HEXADECIMAIS** e trabalhar eles.

Exemplificando o **hexadecimal character escape(\x)**:

```
print("Capacidade   - \x0a 10kg  \x0b") # agora podemos ver mais por trás dos bastidores
```

**Exemplo final:**

```
print("\x4f\x6c\x61\x21") # rode este código e entenderá melhor.
```