# Quais são e qual a função de cada prefixo de string no Python?

Tags: python, string, característica-linguagem

No Python, é comum vermos *strings* com um prefixo, tal como abaixo, onde utiliza-se o prefixo `r`:

```
r"""OS routines for NT or Posix depending on what system we're on.
This exports:
  - all functions from posix or nt, e.g. unlink, stat, etc.
  - os.path is either posixpath or ntpath
  - os.name is either 'posix' or 'nt'
  - os.curdir is a string representing the current directory (always '.')
  - os.pardir is a string representing the parent directory (always '..')
  - os.sep is the (or a most common) pathname separator ('/' or '\\')
  - os.extsep is the extension separator (always '.')
  - os.altsep is the alternate pathname separator (None or '/')
  - os.pathsep is the component separator used in $PATH etc
  - os.linesep is the line separator in text files ('\r' or '\n' or '\r\n')
  - os.defpath is the default search path for executables
  - os.devnull is the file path of the null device ('/dev/null', etc.)
Programs that import and use 'os' stand a better chance of being
portable between different platforms.  Of course, they must then
only use functions that are defined by all platforms (e.g., unlink
and opendir), and leave all pathname manipulation to os.path
(e.g., split and join).
"""
```

<sup>Trecho retirado do código fonte do módulo `os`, acessado via [repositório oficial](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py).</sup>

- Quais são todos os prefixos existentes no Python?
- Qual a função de cada um dos prefixos?
- Qual o impacto do prefixo no valor, tipo e tamanho da *string*?

É desejável que a resposta aborde tanto para a versão 2 quanto 3 da linguagem, assim como descrever as diferenças, se existir, entre as versões.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80545/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Então - vamos lá - quando eu disser Python, estou falando de Python3; vamos assumir que Python2 é uma coisa do passado. (Eu falo das strings em Python2, mas é justamente um dos pontos em que houve a maior mudança)

- Uso de `'` ou `"` para delimitar *strings*: não há diferença alguma. Use o que você preferir ou o que for mais conveniente para delimitar suas *strings* de qualquer dos tipos.
- Uso de aspas triplas - `"""` ou `'''`: indica que a *string* só termina quando encontrar uma aspas tripla correspondente e vai incluir tudo no caminho: outras aspas, mudanças de linha, etc... é ideal para colocar pequenos trechos de outras linguagens, como SQL ou HTML quando necessário, ou para colocar comentários que incluam documentação.
- *Strings* sem prefixo algum, ou com prefixo `u"`: Em Python3, o "u" não faz nada. Ele foi introduzido no Python 3.3 (se não me falha a memória) para facilitar a escrita de código que funcionasse tanto em Python2 quanto em Python3, sem modificações. Já em Python2, uma *string* prefixada com `u"` indica que se trata de uma *string* "unicode": isso é, ela é tratada pelo Python como *texto*, não como uma sequência de bytes. Em uma *string* unicode o Python sabe que cada elemento é um caractere, ao passo que em uma *string* de bytes, você depende da codificação de texto para ler cada elemento e, em algumas codificações, um caractere usa mais de um byte.  Assim, em Python2, em uma *string* sem o `u`, se você tentar converter uma palavra como "maçã" para maiúsculas num sistema Unix (Android, Linux, Mac OS), que usam UTF-8, por padrão, vai terminar com "MAçã" em vez de "maçã" (**e mais ainda: len("maçã") retorna "6" e não "4"**). Com *strings* unicode, o "ç" e o "ã" são entendidos como letras. É importantíssimo entender o que é texto unicode - vital para programar, na verdade. Eu recomendo a leitura [deste artigo, escrito há mais de 10 anos por um dos fundadores do stackoverflow.](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)). Mas, refraseando pra ficar claro: **em Python3, toda *string* é unicode por padrão, exceto as que tem o prefixo "b". Em Python2, toda *string* é só uma sequência de bytes, exceto as que tem o prefixo "u".**

Um programa correto em Python2 deveria ter todas as strings com o prefixo "u". Em Python 3, ocasionalmente você vai ter em mãos uma *string* de bytes, que é um objeto `bytes`: em geral quando usa uma biblioteca de baixo nível como `sockets`, ou quando abre um arquivo para leitura no modo binário. Nesse caso, o que você deve fazer sempre antes de tentar trabalhar com o texto é *decodificar* a *string*: uma *string* de bytes sempre vai estar codificada com alguma codificação - seja "latin1", "utf-8", "cp852" para o terminal do DOS,"cp1251" para Russo, "cp1253" para grego, etc. Então você executa o método `decode` do próprio objeto `bytes` transformando isso numa *string* apropriada de texto. No Python 2, a mesma coisa - o mesmo método `decode`, e você tem uma *string* "unicode", que pode ser usada como texto. Mais cuidado, na verdade MUITO cuidado é necessário para programar corretamente em Python2, porque a maior parte das pessoas não sabe sobre esses passos de unicode ou não unicode. Isso leva a programas que usam o texto da forma incorreta. Em Python3, a maior parte das operações de texto não é nem permitida, ou funcionam de forma diferente, com *strings* de bytes, incentivando o uso correto das *strings* (que são unicode). Por exemplo: em Python2 é possível concatenar com `+` uma *string* de bytes e uma *string* de texto.  Só que, se a *string* de bytes tiver apenas um caractere fora da faixa ASCII (0 até 127), como por exemplo, um caractere acentuado, o Python dá um erro. Isso causa erros intermitentes no seu programa, se você concatena duas variáveis e uma delas não contém unicode, e já tirou o sono de muita gente:

```
>>> u"maç" + "ã"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

(Mas u"maç" + "a" funciona).  Em Python 3 esta é sempre uma operação ilegal: você tem que converter tudo pra texto antes de tentar concatenar. Isso faz com que todos vejam o erro em qualquer execução do programa e fica fácil para o desenvolvedor corrigir. Do jeito que o Python 2 faz, o erro pode passar despercebido e só causar problemas na produção.

- Prefixo `b`: implica que o objeto entre aspas não é uma *string* de texto, mas um objeto do tipo `bytes`. Ela é mais ou menos equivalente a *string* sem prefixo nenhum que existia em Python2. No Python3 no entanto, um objeto `bytes` é bem diferente do que o objeto "bytes" em Python2: em particular quando você tenta usar o operador de `[ ]` para recuperar um único elemento de um objeto desses, o Python retorna um número, entre 0 e 255: o valor do byte naquela posição. (A mesma coisa se você usar um objeto desse tipo num comando `for` ):

  ```
   >>> for char in "maçã":

   ...    print(char, end=" ")
   ... 
   m a ç ã [in 2] 
   >>> for char in b"maçã":
   ...    print(char, end=" ")
   ... 
   File "<stdin>", line 1
   SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
   >>> for char in b"maca":
  ...    print(char, end=" ")
  ... 
  109 97 99 97
  ```

Isso é em Python 3. Python 2 imprimiria as 4 letras. Como você pode ver, o Python 3 sequer permite que você coloque caracteres fora da faixa 32-127 dentro de um literal de bytes, com o prefixo `b"`. (Se precisar fazer isso, você deve usar o o escape `\xHH` e colocar o código, em hexadecimal, diretamente na *string*)

- Prefixo `r"`: indica uma literal "raw" (cru): dentro dessa *string*, o caractere de barra invertida não tem o papel especial de servir de "escape" para caracteres especiais. Numa *string* normal de Python, algumas sequências tais como "\n", "\t", "\b" não representam dois caracteres, e sim, um único caractere de controle (nesse caso, respectivamente "new line" de código 10, "tab", código 9, e "backspace" de código 8). Com o prefixo `b`, a "barra" passa a ser sempre a barra e o caractere seguinte é sempre ele mesmo. Por isso, quando se coloca nomes de arquivo no Windows com o caractere "\" para separar diretórios precisa se colocar o prefixo `r"`. Senão, seus nomes de arquivo funcionam para letras que não estão definidas como sequências, mas vai dar errado se  a `\` preceder um caractere que forme uma sequência especial. (Esses caracteres denotados pela sequência começando com "\" são uma herança da linguagem C, aliás).

> Dica para Windows: você pode, e deveria, usar o caractere "/" para separar diretórios - funciona dentro do Python.

Outro uso frequente para as strings com `r"` é quando se define expressões regulares. Porque essas usam as sequências começando com `\` para seus próprios propósitos - se o Python transformar a sequência "\n" num único caractere de código 10, o código das expressões regulares nem veria a  `\`.

Podemos fazer um parenteses e mencionar três tipos importantíssimos de escape com `\`:  `\xHH` (substitua cada "H" por um dígito hexadecimal) permite colocar qualquer código de 0 a 255 dentro de uma *string*. Em objetos de texto, caracteres nesta faixa *coincidem* com a codificação latin1 - ou seja, qualquer número colocado depois do `\x` vai gerar um caractere válido. Outro é o `\uHHHH`: 4 dígitos em hexadecimal que permitem especificar qualquer caractere unicode com código 65536. Uma busca na web, ou melhor, imprimindo-se os caracteres no console do Python, permite que você ache as letras de vários alfabetos distintos, dezenas de *emojis* e centenas de outros símbolos (incluindo, por exemplo, as peças de xadrez). O prefixo `\UHHHHHHHH` permite especificar um código de até 8 dígitos hexadecimais e permite o uso de caracteres de código acima de 65536.

- Combinação de "u" ou "b" com "r": tanto o "u" como "b" podem ser usados em conjunto com "r": `ur"maçã \b"`, porque o "r" não muda o conteúdo interno da *string*, apenas como os caracteres entre aspas vão ser interpretados.  A combinação não traz surpresas em Python2 ou Python3.
- Strings com `f"`: novidade no Python 3.6, não existe em nenhuma versão anterior: cria um objeto especial que é resolvido no momento da compilação do programa e permite inserir dentro da própria *string*, valores de variáveis, contas numéricas, ou qualquer expressão em Python, sem que seja necessário chamar o método `format`;

Exemplo:

```
nome = "João"; 
print(f"Meu nome é {nome}")  # Meu nome é João
```

- Os objetos do tipo `f"` também podem ser combinados com o prefixo "r": `fr"..."`.

São esses os tipos que existem como prefixo das aspas. Recapitulando, em Python 3: `b"`: objeto do tipo "bytes", `u"`: o mesmo que nenhum prefixo, só existe para ser fácil escrever código compatível entre Python 2 e 3, `r"` para *strings* "cruas" onde a "\" é sempre uma "\", *strings* `f"` que podem incluir outros objetos e expressões diretamente, e combinações de `u`, `b` ou `f` com `r`;

Answer (score 2):

No Python 2.7, você tem as seguintes opções:

- s = 'cachorro': String ASCII
- s = u'cão': String Unicode que aceita caracteres especiais e acentos (á,º,§, etc)
- s = r'cao\n\t\r': String Raw, que interpreta os caracteres da forma que estão.

Exemplos possíveis:

```
>>> s = 'cão' # erro, pois 'ã' não é ASCII
>>> s = u'cão' # OK, pois 'ã' é unicode

>>> s = 'cachorro\n' # interpreta o \n como quebra de linha
>>> print s
cachorro

>>> s = r'cachorro\n' # interpreta o \n como '\n'
>>> print s
cachorro\n

>>> s = u'cão\n' # interpreta o \n como quebra de linha
>>> print s
cão

>>> s = ur'cão\n' # interpreta o \n como '\n'
>>> print s
cão\n
```

Comment: E no Python 3? E as combinações delas? Qual o impacto de cada uma na string?