# Identificar uma sequência numérica em um arquivo texto

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Sou novo em Python, e to com um problema que não estou encontrando solução. Tenho uma pasta com cerca de 10k de .txt (escritos dos mais variados jeitos).
Preciso extrair a PRIMEIRA sequência de 17 números que fica localizado nas primeiras linhas desses txt`s, e renomear o arquivo com a sequência extraída.

Essa sequência por vezes aparece concatenada outras vezes aparece separadas por ponto e hífen (ex: 00273200844202003, 00588.2007.011.02.00-9)
PS: existem outras sequências numéricas no texto diferente ou igual a 17 numeros, mas a sequencia é sempre a primeira de 17 que aparece.

Armazenei os nomes atuais dos documentos em uma lista, estava tentando achar a sequência de números no texto usando o pacote NLTK mas sem sucesso.

```
pasta_de_documentos = (r'''C:\Users\mateus.ferreira\Desktop\Estudos\Python\Doc_Classifier\TXT''')
documentos = os.listdir(pasta_de_documentos)
```

Se alguém souber uma melhor abordagem ou puder me dar um caminho pra continuar atacando o problema agradeço. (Estou utilizando Python 3)

Comment: Quando separado por pontos e hifens, esses caracteres estão sempre nas mesmas posições dentro do número ou podem variar?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss os caracteres quando aparecem pelo que olhei na mão, aparecem nas mesmas posições

Comment: E por quê quando há os caracteres separando o número possui 20 dígitos? Não deveria ser sempre 17?

Comment: Vi agora que acabei copiando a sequência errada de números no meu exemplo, já corrigi, obrigado. O exemplo correto seria 00588.2007.011.02.00-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é buscar o valor através de uma expressão regular. Para satisfazer as duas possibilidades, você pode definir como opcional a presença dos pontos e hifens entre os dígitos. Ficaria algo como:

```
r'(\d{5}\.?\d{4}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{2}\.?\d{2}\-?\d)'
```

O [prefixo `r`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255271/5878) define a *string* como crua. Os parenteses criam um grupo de captura para a expressão regular e caracteriza esse grupo como sendo:

- Sequência de 5 dígitos;
- Podendo, ou não, ser seguida de um ponto;
- Sequência de 4 dígitos;
- Podendo, ou não, ser seguida de um ponto;
- Sequência de 3 dígitos;
- Podendo, ou não, ser seguida de um ponto;
- Sequência de 2 dígitos;
- Podendo, ou não, ser seguida de um ponto;
- Sequência de 2 dígitos;
- Podendo, ou não, ser seguida de um hífen;
- Sequência de 1 dígito;

Com Python, você pode utilizar o módulo `re` para tratar o conteúdo do arquivo junto com a expressão regular:

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as content:
    search = re.search(r'(\d{5}\.?\d{4}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{2}\.?\d{2}\-?\d)', content.read())
    if search is not None:
        print(search.group(0))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PerfectFirebrickKingsnake)</sup>

Assim, o valor de `search.group(0)` será o primeiro valor de 17 dígitos, com separadores ou não, encontrado no arquivo `data.txt`. Se você possui múltiplos arquivos, basta você percorrer todos eles e executar a mesma lógica. Aproveite e leia sobre o módulo [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), talvez lhe seja útil.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar expressões regulares para isso.

Uma expressão regular que ache toda as sequências que podem conter dígitos,  "-" e ".", com no mínimo 17 elementos - seria possível refinar a expressão até ela achar por si mesma 17 dígitos, mas eu acho que fica complexo demais - então prefiro combinar a expressão regular com alguma lógica em Python.

Como os arquivos são pequenos (10Kb, mas mesmo que fossem 30 vezes maiores),náo e necessário alguma lógica para ler só parte do arquivo e fazer a busca ali. Mas na da impede também que você leia os primeiros 4KB de cada arquivo se a sequência estiver sempre lá (~400 linhas se as linhas não forem grandes).

```
import os, re

def encontra_nome(pasta, nome_do_arquivo):
    dados = open(os.path.join(pasta, nome_do_arquivo)).read(4096)
    sequencias = re.findall(r"[0-9\.\-]{17, 35}", dados)
    for seq in sequencias:
        sequencia_limpa = re.sub("\-|\.", "", a)
        if len sequencia_limpa >= 17:
             return sequencia
    raise ValueError ("Sequencia de 17 dígitos não encontrada")
```

A expressão regular `r"[0-9\.\-]{17, 35}"` busca, como descrevi, qualquer sequência dentre 17 e 35 repetições de caracteres dentre dígitos, "-" e ".". Isso permite até um separador após cada dígito, então deve cobrir todos os formatos possíveis. Preferi isso em vez de complicar a expressão regular - por que não são nem especialmente legíveis, nem fáceis de fazer, para "contar apenas os dígitos e ignorar os outros caractéres, e achar 17 exatamente".  Uma única expressão regular para isso certamente seria possível. Em vez disso, uma vez achados todos os candidatos, uso uma busca linear com um `for`, filtro os - e . - desta vez com uma expressão regular bem simples que substitui todos os "-" e "." por "".

Eu prefiro as vezes usar duas chamadas ao método replace das strings em vez de fazer isso, mas já que já estamos fazendo uso de expressões regulares, não tem por que não usar mais uma: não há barreiras de performance ou algo do tipo, mas sim barreias de "ops, lá vem uma expressão regular" de pessoas mantendo o seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o módulo `glob` para recuperar uma lista contendo o nome de todos os arquivos `.txt` em um dado diretório.

Iterando nessa lista, você pode abrir cada um dos arquivos, fazendo a leitura apenas da primeira linha e extraindo dela apenas os digitos:

```
linha = entrada.readline()
digitos = (''.join(s for s in linha if s.isdigit()))
```

Desses digitos lidos, somente os `17` primeiros seriam considerados e concatenados com a extensão `.txt`:

```
destino = digitos[:17] + '.txt'
```

Uma vez com o nome do arquivo de saída montado, você pode usar o módulo `shutil` para duplicar o arquivo com o novo nome.

Segue um exemplo capaz de solucionar o seu problema:

```
import shutil
import glob


# Recupera listagem de todos os arquivos .txt de um dado diretorio...
lista_arquivos = glob.glob('/tmp/teste/*.txt')

# Para cada arquivo na lista
for origem in lista_arquivos:

    # Abre arquivo de origem para leitura em modo texto
    with open( origem ) as entrada:

        # Le apenas a primeira linha do arquivo de origem
        linha = entrada.readline()

        # Extrai somente os digitos da linha lida
        digitos = (''.join(s for s in linha if s.isdigit()))

        # Formata o nome do arquivo de destino
        destino = digitos[:17] + '.txt'

    # Exibe status do processamento
    print("{} -> {}".format( origem, destino ))

    # Copia arquivo de origem para o destino
    shutil.copyfile( origem, destino );
```