# Adicionar Texto Em textbox em determinada posição C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um software odontológico o qual uma das funções é de selecionar um dente em um button e adicionar o nome deste dente em uma textbox. Até ai sem problemas, mas a questão é que essa textbox é referente a observações, e gostaria que o nome de cada dente selecionado, fosse adicionado na textbox em linhas diferentes e não lado a lado. Então conforme cada button referente a cada dente é selecionado vai adicionando o nome dos dentes um em cada linha. 
Por exemplo, quando clico em button1 é adicionado o texto "Bot1" na textbox e assim por diante, o problema é que caso eu clique em mais de um button o texto deve ir para linhas diferentes e não na mesma. É isso que eu gostaria mas não consigo desenvolver uma logica para fazer isso alguém tem alguma ideia?

segue o evento click que estou usando nos buttons:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Texto = txtObservacao.Text;
        txtObservacao.Text += "Terceiro Molar Inf.Direito (48):";
        if (btnMolar48.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightSeaGreen))
        {
            btnMolar48.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            txtObservacao.Text = Texto.Replace("Terceiro Molar Inf.Direito (48):", "");
        }
        else
        {
            btnMolar48.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightSeaGreen);
        }
    }

    private void btnMolar47_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Texto = txtObservacao.Text;
        txtObservacao.Text += "\n" + "Segundo Molar Inf.Direito(47):";
        if (btnMolar47.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightSeaGreen))
        {
            btnMolar47.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            txtObservacao.Text = Texto.Replace("Segundo Molar Inf.Direito(47):", "");
        }
        else
        {
            btnMolar47.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightSeaGreen);
        }
    }`
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem, basicamente, dois tipos de quebras de linha CR (carriage return - `\n`)  e LF (line feed - `\r`).

Você pode ler um pouco sobre isso aqui em [Qual a diferença entre carriage return e line feed?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93444/18246)

Possivelmente você está usando o tipo o errado, para evitar esse tipo estresse e até mesmo para ter completa certeza de que seu código funcionará mesmo em outras máquinas é possível usar o **`Environment.NewLine`**.

Exemplo:

```
textBox.Text = "Linha 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Linha 2";
```

Comment: Tem também os dois juntos, que é o `\r\n`. Só não sei o nome dele. E se não me engano, o `Environment.NewLine` usa este valor mencionado.

Comment: É a junção dos dois (seria CRLF). O `Environment.NewLine` usa o caracter adequado de acordo com a plataforma que está sendo usada (o Windows usa ambos)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando System.Environment.NewLine.

`string Texto = txtObservacao.Text;
            txtObservacao.Text += System.Environment.NewLine;
            txtObservacao.Text +=  "Segundo Molar Inf.Direito(47):";
            if (btnMolar47.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightSeaGreen))
            {
                btnMolar47.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                txtObservacao.Text = Texto.Replace("Segundo Molar Inf.Direito(47):", "");
            }
            else
            {
                btnMolar47.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightSeaGreen);
            }`

Peço perdão se não fui claro na minha questão a cima, mas quem respondeu, meu sincero obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 int h =3;
```

Button newButton = new Button();
    Button[] buttonArray = new Button[8];

```
for (int i = 0; i <= h-1; i++)
{
  buttonArray[i] = new Button();
 buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(20, 43);
  buttonArray[i].Name= ""+i+"";
  buttonArray[i].Click += button_Click;//function
  buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(40, 20 + (i * 20));
  panel1.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);

}  }
```

Comment: O que o seu código faz? Ele resolve o problema da pergunta? Se sim, tem como explicar-nos como ele faz isso?