# Por que devemos usar PHP_EOL?

Tags: php, string

Já me informaram que o `PHP_EOL` define o fim da linha, ok.

Mas por que eu deveria escrever.

```
echo 'a'.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'b';
```

Se o

```
echo 'a'.'<br>';
echo 'b';
```

Traz o mesmo efeito, qual a diferença que faz usar o `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Primeiro é importante você entender que o `.` é uma coisa e o `PHP_EOL` é outra. O `.` é só um operador para concatenar duas strings. No caso, `PHP_EOL` é uma delas, mais precisamente é uma constante que contém uma string. A string exata que ela contém depende do sistema operacional. Agora (re)leia a resposta do Maniero :)

Comment: Não trás o mesmo efeito, isso só parece igual em HTML, se o `content-type:` for `text/plain` BR não será uma tag, será texto e sem o PHP_EOL não haverá quebra de linha, deixando tudo em uma linha só, no entanto PHP_EOL é um pouco desnecessário neste seu exemplo, tanto apostrofos quanto aspas suportam ter quebras de linhas reais dentro e para faciltar você pode usar o heredoc.

Comment: @bfavaretto, muito obrigado pela resposta, o "." foi um erro meu, na hora de copiar, o código do editor, ele acabou vindo junto, mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Comment: Mas agora você incluiu o `;` do final que também é outra coisa :D

Comment: Quase nunca deve. PHP_EOL não é "fim de linha". É somente o "fim da linha do OS em que o  PHP está rodando naquele momento". Nem mais,nem menos. Se usar em email está errado, se usar em HTTP está errado, se usar em remessa bancária está errado, e a lista de onde  é errado usar é imensa.  Só deve usar na minoria de situações em que a quebra seja a mesma do padrão do OS em que o script está rodando (um log local, por ex). Os exemplos que eu dei (e a grande maioria dos arquivos) tem formato definido por RFC ou documentação específica, e não devem usar quebras que variam de acordo com o ambiente.

Comment: Um adendo ao comentário do @Bacco só para ter uma noção de como difere, o `var_dump(PHP_EOL);` em Windows retorna isto `\r\n` em ambientes unix-like "geralmente" retorna isto `\n` (claro que não exatamente isto que você vê, isso ai é a representação) e provavelmente se o PHP rodasse em outros sistemas (não sei se roda) existem (existiam?) os que usavam `\025`, então se teoricamente você usar PHP_EOL para páginas web e o servidor usasse `\025` com certeza tudo iria quebrar/falhar.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eita verdade, obrigador, não avia observado isso.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não é que deve usar, você usa se quiser e precisar. Primeiro, só vai usá-lo se você quer dar um pulo de linha no texto gerado. É o que você quer aí? Sabe por que vai pular linha ali?

Esse pulo de linha tem a ver com o texto gerado, não com o HTML. o `<br>` nada tem a ver com isso, por acaso nesse código é assim, mas pular linha aí só muda o *layout* do código e não da página que ele desenhará. Não se esqueça que você está gerando um texto que é um código a ser mandado para um *browser*. Esse pulo de linha que está falando afetará só esse texto, não o que ele renderizará.

O primeiro código gerará no *browser* algo assim:

```
a<br>
b
```

O segundo ficará assim no *browser*:

```
a<br>b
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/BreakLine.html).

Mas na hora que for montar a página e mostrada os dois mostrarão exatamente a mesma coisa (salvo algum *bug* no *browser*) porque para renderizar a página o que vale é só o `<br>`, e não a quebra de linha.

Se realmente quer pular linha pode usar um caractere puro de pular linha ou pode usar esta constante definida que usará o caractere apropriado para pular linha de acordo com o sistema operacional que o seu código está rodando. Mas como estamos falando de um texto gerado para o HTML isso não tem relevância, e na verdade nem faz sentido já que se ele estiver rodando no Linux, por exemplo, e seu HTML gerado for para um *browser* rodando no Windows, ele gerou uma quebra de linha de um jeito que o Windows não entende corretamente (pode ser que o *browser* faça alguma coisa para administrar isso).

[Documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

Para este caso um `\n` no lugar do `PHP_EOL` deve funcionar bem. O `PHP_EOL` faz mais sentido quando vai criar arquivos que precisam ser mostrados em uma plataforma específica mas você não sabe qual será ela ainda. O *browser* não tem como você controlar, quando você manda o HTML para o cliente via servidor HTTP tem que escolher uma forma, aí costuma ser tarde demais, a não ser que tente detectar que plataforma o *browser* que fez a requisição está rodando (não é confiável), mas aí tem que fazer o oposto do que o `PHP_EOL` faz, você teria que controlar isso.

O resumo de tudo isso é que não precisa usar esta constante, não sei o contexto, mas parece que alguém te orientou errado, pelo menos para este contexto.

Parti do princípio que sabe o que é concatenação de *string*.

Leia os comentários que tem informações relevantes sobre porque isto existe e quando deve ser usado de verdade. É raro ser necessário em PHP e geralmente só quando ele é usado para coisas que não é o normal que as pessoas fazem.

Pode ler mais em [Qual a diferença entre carriage return e line feed?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93444/101).

Answer (score 0):

### Quebra de Linha no Console

- Para resolver questões de diferentes sistemas operacionais utilize o PHP_EOL para forçar uma quebra de linha na visualização.

As alternativas abaixo funcionaram de forma idêntica no ambiente `Windows`, já para outro `OS`, LF+CR poderiam não ter o mesmo resultado.

```php
echo "Pula linha 1", PHP_EOL;
echo "Pula linha 2" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Pula linha 3" . chr(10) . chr(13);
```

*Obs: chr(10) = LF(line feed), chr(13) = CR (carriage return). Veja em tabela ascii :[https://web.fe.up.pt/~ee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Eee96100/projecto/Tabela%20ascii.htm)*

Answer (score -3):

A diferença aparecerá dependendo onde o texto será inserido, se na página ou em um elemento tipo textarea. Para visualizar, tente isso:

```
<?php
function p(){
    echo 'A' . "\n";
    echo 'B' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'C' . "\n";
    echo 'C' . '\n';
    echo 'D' . '<br />';
    echo 'F' . chr(10);
    echo 'E' . '<br />';
}
p();
echo '<textarea style="height:100px;">';
p();
echo '</textarea>';
?>
```